# Customizing markers in OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm working with OpenStreetMap and have successfully added markers to the map that, when clicked, show a popup window.
I would like, if possible, to customize markers not only by changing the image, but adding an HTML DIV under the icon with a number/text different for every marker.
How can i do it?
I use javascript and php to fill the map

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers or how are you displaying the map?

Comment: Yes, i'm using OpenLayers for displaying the map

Comment: I don't believe that you can do this with out of the box functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Can’t labels fit your needs ?

See http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/vector-features-with-text.html

```
            var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
                strokeColor: "#00FF00",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 3,
                fillColor: "#FF5500",
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                pointRadius: 6,
                pointerEvents: "visiblePainted",
                // label with \n linebreaks
                label : "name: ${name}\n\nage: ${age}",
                
                fontColor: "${favColor}",
                fontSize: "12px",
                fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                labelAlign: "${align}",
                labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
                labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
                labelOutlineColor: "white",
                labelOutlineWidth: 3
            }}),
            renderers: renderer
        });
        
        // create a point feature
        var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-111.04, 45.68);
        var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
        pointFeature.attributes = {
            name: "toto",
            age: 20,
            favColor: 'red',
            align: "cm"
        };
```

Comment: Please paste things here for posterity in the future. The site is now a 404.

Comment: @Noah future is safe (-; , link fixed

Comment: too bad you didn't past more information here, the site is 404 again

Comment: @hugogogo I just update my answer with code from linked example.

Comment: great :) the site is available for you ?

Comment: No, but the source for openlayers 2 branch is archived in one accessible repository: https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/blob/master/examples/vector-features-with-text.html